# How to send automated emails to each user about their content in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a Drupal site which lets users create an account and publish their own content. However I have been trying for hours with no luck to try and set up an email service which sends an email to all the users with content every week for example. The email will show them how many page hits their content has got. Any help will be much appreciated! Cheers

Comment: can you point out the specific issues you are facing... it looks like you want to achieve lots of things. how to setup cron, how to collect relevant data ( what are those relevant data?), how to send email using drupal can you split your question in to more specific questions so its easier to give an answer. If you are concerned about performance and timeouts , mention them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me and my colleague have found a solution. We first created a rule which will run on a cron job to execute the custom php below.

```
$type = '<node_type>';

$articles = db_select('node')
->fields('node', array('nid', 'title'))
->condition('type', $type, '=')
->execute()
->fetchAllKeyed();

$nodes = array();
foreach ($articles as $nid => $title) {
    $nodes[] = node_load($nid);
}

$checked = array();

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    if(!in_array($node->nid, $checked)) {
        $statistics = statistics_get($node->nid);
        $email = $node->field_email['und'][0]['email'];
        $subject = 'Content view update';
        $headers = 'From: you@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: you@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        $message =   'Hi,
        Your content has been viewed ' . $statistics . ' times';

        global $language;
        $params['subject'] = t($subject);
        $params['body']    = array(t($message));

        drupal_mail('smtp', 'smtp-test', $email, $language, $params);
        $checked[] = $node->nid;

    }
}
```

The php script loops through all of the custom content nodes with type `$type` and retrieves the title, email and statistics then emails the information to the content owner.

If anyone has a better solution please can you comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you have to use [drupal rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules)  modeule.